# Extract string literal union from array of classes based on constructor parameters

Tags: javascript, typescript, class

I am trying to get a string literal union based on values passed to an array of classes via constructor.

For example, the array looks like this:

```js
const myArray = [
  new MyClass({
    key: "key1", 
  }),
  new MyClass({
    key: "key2", 
  }), 
]
```

And I'm trying to construct a mapped version of it (for lookup) or a string literal union:

```js
type MyUnionType = "key1" | "key2"
```

The primary reason for this is to ensure that any lookups use available keys assigned to the class.

```js
getClass('key1') // all good 

getClass('notAKey') // error
```

However all solutions I've seen so far include some form of redundancy in either passing the key as a generic or creating an object with the same keys.

Comment: Sounds like you want an [enum](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html) Then you can say the my class constructor takes an interface of `{ key: EnumName }`

Comment: Given `myArray` has type `MyClass[]` (or `MyClass<…>[]`?), please share the definition of `MyClass`. It's not possible to extract the types of the arguments that were passed to the constructor calls, it's only possible to extract the types from instances in the array. What properties do they have?

Comment: Using an enum again becomes redundant (define the enum and define the key)

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
type MyUnionType = {
  [K in keyof typeof myArray]:
    (typeof myArray)[K] extends MyClass<infer T> ? T : never
}[number]
```

This is a mapped type that goes over each key in the array, and then infers the generic parameter from each member of `myArray`.

This assumes a class like:

```
class MyClass<T extends string> {
  constructor(options: { key: T }) {}
}
```

Which you would use like:

```
const myArray = [
  new MyClass({
    key: "key1", 
  }),
  new MyClass({
    key: "key2", 
  }), 
] as const

function getClass(input: MyUnionType) {}
getClass('key1') // works
getClass('notAKey') // error
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=6&jsx=0&module=1&ssl=22&ssc=29&pln=6&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCeBhcUA8AVaBTAHgFywDsATGCPAJwEtCBzAPmgG8AoaaYAe0PIoFdgeThQAUnAA54q3CAC5m0ANZZ48zAF8AlM3UtdLFlx55oAW3gBBChTDxoAXmgBtNtEJYA7nCQoII1uzsyqrQAETBAIyhADTQrlrRru5eCMiQfgGBwfLhKgBMMXHsCXEAutCQHDJ4Bnjw4ljeAKqE0oTo9Y2OmU4A0tA0SiqcAGbQdQ2jZpbWtqWyruwiE1hT5lY28Jp95bgEJDCpvqg0I1gU0OiMAPyX0PLuAG7nek6EfKYARuelBiN8hEEbWgtCweDSUBENHEfDw8gQLTaHQa2iYulB4N8IgA5JFsdoAPQE6AeYSKCAsDEQvzYwicPAWXoqfHQInYazCIA)

---

Or, parameterized for more flexibility:

```
type MyUnionType<T extends readonly MyClass<string>[]> = {
  [K in keyof T]:
    T[K] extends MyClass<infer U> ? U : never
}[number]

function getClass(input: MyUnionType<typeof myArray>) {}
getClass('key1') // works
getClass('notAKey') // error
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=6&jsx=0&module=1&ssl=22&ssc=29&pln=15&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCeBhcUA8AVaBTAHgFywDsATGCPAJwEtCBzAPmgG8AoaaYAe0PIoFdgeThQAUnAA54q3CAC5m0ANZZ48zAF8AlM3UtdLFlx55oAW3gBBChTDxoAXmgBtNtEJYA7nCQoII1uzsyqrQAETBAIyhADTQrlrRru5eCMiQfgGBwfLhKgBMMXHsCXEAutCQHDJ4Bnjw4ljeAKqE0oTo9VgY2PhEpNAUWGDE3CB2qb6ovDQMTqWMjplOANLQNEoqnABm0Oilsq7s6CvluAQkMBPpqDRbWBTQTYwA-I-Q8u4Abvd6ToR8pgARvdSgYtnxCII2tBaFg8GkoCIaOI+Hh5AgWm0Og1UHUGtszJZrLZ6NomLpYfDfCIAOSRGnaAD0jOgHmEiggLEpCL8NMInDwFmWKgZ0GZ2GswiAA)

Comment: Great answer Alex, #respect